# How to implicitly link libraries?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation, linker, g++

I have a library called A.a, and its .hpp file called A.hpp. When programs need to use this library, they #include "A.hpp", and get linked to it like this: g++ test1.cpp A.a -o test1. I'd like to be able to only compile it like this g++ test1.cpp -o test1, without explicitly typing A.a in there, just like I don't need to explicitly link my program with iostream. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This can be done by e.g. modifying compiler specs. But you really don't want to do that. Why is telling the compiler what to do (in a simple way) an issue?

Comment: I guess it is better to use some tool like `make` to manage linking.

Comment: @halfelf: In pretty much any build system one needs to add some sort of dependency on `A.a`, so it cannot be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done on Visual C++ (the compiler can embed some linker options in object files, requests to link a library being one of those that are possible).

Gcc (and, to my knowledge, clang) do not have such a feature. You have to provide the libraries on the command line; there is no way around it (build tools are not technically a way around it; they also put the libraries onto the command lines they use to run the linker).

Comment: But it clearly does work in the iostream example I gave, doesn't it?